# Fitnesse Testing Framwrok for appian, Getting error instead of Report while run TestExample script

Tags: fitnesse, fitnesse-slim, appian

I m getting error in Execution log . Script ran successfully but in execution log getting errro message. pasted below.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

It’s not actually an error, but a warning that you are using a (slightly) outdated chromedriver. Nothing to worry about.

Don’t know how you install chromedriver, but generally each chrome version installed also wants an updated chromedriver on your system

Comment: Thank you sir for your answer.
I just created Directory "Drivers" inside lib and added chromeSetup as shown in pic.
Due to this Warning or Error i m not getting Report of Script. that is reason i m worrry about it.

Comment: ERROR StatusLogger Reconfiguration failed: No configuration found for '4e0e2f2a' at 'null' in 'null

Sep 14, 2023 3:23:01 PM org.openqa.selenium.devtools.CdpVersionFinder findNearestMatch
WARNING: Unable to find an exact match for CDP version 116, so returning the closest version found: 115

Comment: I'm sorry but I'm no appian user. On https://community.appian.com/b/appmarket/posts/fitnesse-for-appian I found that Appian provides support via https://community.appian.com/support. Maybe you can get help there?